# How to verify my application registered with Gracenote?

Tags: c#, xml, post, webclient, gracenote

I am trying to register my application, which is written in C#, with Gracenote for my senior seminar class. I believe I have done it correctly, but to my understanding when I call a `WebClient.UploadData()` method, I should have what is returned displayed in my output window. Nothing came up.

Since you are supposed to register your application with Gracenote only once per installation, I'm kind of at a standstill since I'm not sure if it registered or not. Below is my code. [`#####-AAAAAA` is my ClientID provided by Gracenote.]

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var dataToPost = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<QUERIES><QUERY CMD=\"REGISTER\"><CLIENT>########-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</CLIENT></QUERY></QUERIES>");
        var result = client.UploadData("https://c########.web.cddbp.net/webapi/xml/1.0/", "POST", dataToPost);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using my C# Gracenote API wrapper here http://www.nuget.org/packages/ParkSquare.Gracenote/

Comment: I swear this is the 3rd time I've commented on this answer. I appreciate your reply! Even though it is past due date for my project, I still went back and implemented the use of your wrapper in my application. I found it easy to use and it really helped pick up the pieces where Last.FM failed on detecting data. My application is currently free and open-source at (http://id3hunter.codeplex.com). Thanks again for providing a C# wrapper for GraceNote! :)